# How to get the total amount of invoices each month in MySQL query with 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables, one for invoices and the other with the items for the invoices. In the invoices table, there is the date of the invoice. What I'm trying to do is to get the total amount of all the invoices each month. In my query, I'm just getting the total amount of only one invoice each month (maybe the last one registered)

This is what I need:

```
| Jan   | $1000 |   (the sum of all items for all invoices in Jan)   
| Feb   | $2300 |   (the sum of all items for all invoices in Feb)
```

And so on...

What I'm getting right now is:

```
| Jan   | $10 | (the sum of the total amount for items of only one invoice in Jan)
| Feb   | $14 | (the sum of the total amount for items of only one invoice in Feb)
```

And so on...

This is my stmt:

```
    SELECT files_fit_invoices.file_inv_num, 
            CASE WHEN files_fit_invoices.file_inv_brk = 'add' 
                    THEN (items.amount - ((items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_comm/100)) + (items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_disc/100))) + (items.amount-(items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_comm/100)) + (items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_disc/100)))*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_tax1/100)) 
                 WHEN files_fit_invoices.file_inv_brk = 'brk' 
                    THEN items.amount - (items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_comm/100)) + (items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_disc/100)) 
                ELSE items.amount-(items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_comm/100)) + (items.amount*(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_disc/100)) 
            END AS H
    FROM files_fit_invoices                          
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT files_fit_invoices_items.file_item_inv, SUM(files_fit_invoices_items.file_item_amount) AS amount 
        FROM files_fit_invoices_items 
        GROUP BY files_fit_invoices_items.file_item_inv
    ) items ON items.file_item_inv = files_fit_invoices.file_inv_num               
    WHERE files_fit_invoices.file_inv_client = :client 
        AND DATE(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_date)>=STR_TO_DATE(:dateini,'%Y-%m-%d') 
        AND DATE(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_date)<=STR_TO_DATE(:datefin,'%Y-%m-%d') 
    GROUP BY MONTH(files_fit_invoices.file_inv_date)");
```

I guess this has something to do with how to group those totals. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Horacio

Comment: Since you're grouping in the main query, you need to use an aggregation function there. Otherwise you just get one row from the group.

Comment: So you need `SUM(CASE ...)`

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. Problem solved. That was it. I added SUM(CASE WHEN 
 ... (files_fit_invoices.file_inv_disc/100)) END) AS H